# Как установить цвет фона заголовка и нижней панели Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, view, ui, dialog

Ставлю в стилях background, но меняется только центральная часть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhlCT.jpg)

Comment: покажите пожалуйста ваши попытки, приведите код показывающий данное UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал, правильная настройка атрибутов следующая:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Dialog.DatePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.Dialog.MaterialDatePicker">
            <item name="materialDatePickerViewStyle">@style/DatePickerStyle</item>
            <item name="colorOnSurface">?attr/colorOnBackground</item>
            <item name="android:background">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
            <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarStyle</item>
            <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarStyle</item>
</style>
    
<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
            <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.DateTimePicker</item>
            <item name="android:background">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
            <item name="highlighterColor">?attr/colorTransparencyOut</item>
            <item name="isShowHighlighter">true</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.DateTimePicker" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.MaterialDateTimePicker">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/base_variant</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/base_variant</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonBarStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
</style>
```